# Add image to taxonomy and output to homepage

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, taxonomy

I want to add an image to my taxonomy terms and then display the image on my homepage. On my index.php template it list the recent 10 posts and I want to show the taxonomy image of the post is in.

I'm currently using `<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'series', ' ', ', ' ); ?>` to show what term the post is in but I also want to show the taxonomy image with it. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Use a plugin like [Category Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) which will let you add an image to a term. This image can then be called where needed on the front end

Comment: How do I call the taxonomy image on the frontpage? their documentation isn't well documented